# Android rootshell: permission denied — sony xperia and MacOSX

Tags: android, macos

so I'm trying to get root access on my Android in order to use Barnacle. But I keep getting the same error, over and over:

```
$ adb shell
$ rootshell
rootshell: permission denied
```

What is the deal with this? I mean, seems logical that I need some permissions to access rootshell, but I can't seem to find any way around it.

Anybody knows how?

Is there any other way to get root access to your phone? (An easy way, hopefully)

EDIT 1:

I will clarify the question.

Unix and Linux systems let you retrieve / change lost passwords for root user. Considering this:

- Is there an easy way to root an Android device using the terminal on my Mac OS X? My device is an Xperia X10 mini pro.
- Or, does anybody know why I get that `permission denied` error using adb and rootshell in the first place? It's supposed to work, as stated [here](http://android.doshaska.net/x10miniroot)?

Thnx!

A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of a question this is or not or whether it is appropriate for StackExchange, but I'm gonna answer it anyway. I don't have enough rep to do anything else about the anyway :D

When you are trying to root any android phone in general, you need to run a program that gives you root access. You can't just simply say "adb give-me-root-permissions-please". :) But yeah, Google is your friend in this case. Apparently your phone the Sony Xperia needs a very specific rooting process that is enumerated here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=711907

I would recommend asking this kind of question THERE on XDA because that site is dedicated to questions like this. This site is for programming questions and the like :)

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I posted the question in SOF because I've looked everywhere for a Mac solution --every workaround demands the use of a PC. Now that you mention it, I see how it could come up as a costumer service kind of question, but it's really about using the android sdk. 
(Great link, btw. Probably will get my answer there.)

Answer (score 0):

TO BE ROOT AT SONY XPERIA
you can use
[king root software](https://www.kingoapp.com/android-root.htm)
or 
[rootkitXperia L](http://fs1.d-h.st/download/00136/wZi/rootkitXperia%28L%29.zip)

how to get temproot by 'getroot'

> usage
>
> push 'getroot' in device, set permission, and execute 'getroot'

```
adb push getroot /data/local/tmp
adb shell
$ cd /data/local/tmp
$ chmod 0755 getroot
$ ./getroot
```

> use CVE-2013-6282 vulnerability
>
> kernel start address 0xc0008000
>
> In some cases, modify KERNEL_START_ADDRESS or KERNEL_SIZE in 'getroot.c'